# Querying a condition where record from database is present in a string?

Tags: sql, database

Basically, what I need is the inverse of this:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `query` LIKE '%string%'
```

Something that looks like:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE '%string%' LIKE 'thestringmachine'
```

I looked up the internet an operation called CONTAINS() but it doesn't seem to work.
Can someone help me?

Edit:

```
$inc = "themachinethatthinks";
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `spell` WHERE CONTAINS('$inc',`word`)");
$num = mysql_numrows($query); $i=0; 

while ($i < $num) {

    $val = mysql_result($query,$i,"word");

    echo $val."<br>";

$i++;
}
```

The database contains lot of words (only).

Comment: Which database server are you using?

Comment: this is for a php script... mysql

Comment: Looks like my mind does not work at the night... could you give an example where `LIKE` pattern matching does not work for you?

Comment: As internet tells me, `CONTAINS` seems to be MSSQL jargon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure I understand what you need, but I try:

```
SELECT * FROM your_table
WHERE LOCATE(your_col, 'thestringmachine') > 0
```

If you need query to be case insensitive:

```
SELECT * FROM your_table
WHERE LOCATE(LOWER(your_col), LOWER('thestringmachine')) > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot try it, 'cause I don't have a SQL DB here at hand, but try this

```
SELECT * FROM `tablename` WHERE `thethinkingmachine' LIKE CONCAT('%', `colname`, '%');
```

If this would work, I doubt it will be very performant.